# Sum of values in a dictionary if part of key is contained in another key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

Given a dictionary, I want the sum of the values of Node 1 with Bank 1, Node 2 with Bank 2 and so on.

data1 = {"Node 1": 256,"Node 2":25,"Bank 1":16,"Bank 2":20}

Expected Output:
272
45

Answer (score 0):

This code will sum all the matching Node-Bank pairs and ignore the rest.

```
data1 = {"Node 1": 256,"Node 2":25, "Bank 1":16,"Bank 2":20}

keys = set([key if "Node" in key else "" for key in list(data1.keys())])
keys.remove("")

for key in keys:
    if "Bank " + str(key.split(" ")[1]) in data1.keys():
        print(data1[key] + data1["Bank " + str(key.split(" ")[1])], end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under the assumption that all your values look exactly like that

You can first split your nodes and banks

```
nodes = {k:v for k,v in data1.items() if k.startswith('Node')}
banks = {k:v for k,v in data1.items() if k.startswith('Bank')}
```

Then just sum the values of the arrays

```
np.array(list(nodes.values())) + np.array(list(banks.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your dictionary will contain are banks and nodes (and without duplicates or missing values), this is easy.

1. Get the number `n` of pairs (which is half the number of elements in the dictionary).
2. Use a for loop with `n` iterations.
3. In each iteration, index the values you need and add them up.

Here is an example to get them as a list.

```py
from json import dumps
data1 = {"Node 1": 256, "Node 2": 25, "Bank 1": 16, "Bank 2": 20}

sums = [0] * len(data1) // 2

for i, sum in enumerate(sums):
    sums[i] = data1[f"Node {i + 1}"] + data1[f"Bank {i + 1}"]

print(sums)
```

**NOTE:** It's ususally un-Pythonic to use an index for lists, but I think this is a really straightforward answer to your question.